# authenticatoin mode="Forms" error

Tags: asp.net, web

I am learning Asp.net and for that I am following video tutorials 
I followed the tutorials exactly as the guy i the videos does but I got that error will anyone help me with this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S96OV.png)

Comment: You have a typo in your title.

Comment: As I said I am just a beginner .. I posted a picture with my question I don't know why its not there .. anyhow the error is  <authentication mode = "Forms "> error  .. called ( configuration error)     It shows me this ...